# Write to the file output of wsadmin scripting

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I want to redirect results out to a file without leaving the wsadmin command line.

Jyhton code :

```
dsid = AdminConfig.getid('/DataSource:IG.JASPER.DS/')
AdminControl.testConnection(dsid)
```

I find something like below. but I am not sure really Can someone please let me know how to do this?

```
file = open("C:\\Test\\conn.txt","w")
file.write("Admin.config.... blah") 
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://jython4wsadmin.blogspot.com/search/label/File%20write%20operation%20in%20Jython) for more details.

*Open the file with "w" or "w+" file mode for writing to a file object.

When a file opened for write operation you can use the following :*

- redirecting operator >>
- write function
- writelines function

So the below script should work for your datasource test connection

```
dsid = AdminConfig.getid('/DataSource:BPH Oracle XA DataSource')
status = AdminControl.testConnection(dsid)

file=open('results.txt', 'w')
#print >>file, status
#file.write(status)
file.write(AdminControl.testConnection(dsid))

file.close()
```

For successful connection, the generated file (results.txt) should contain an entry like "*WASX7217I: Connection to provided datasource was successful.*"